# TicTacToe Winning situations

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

i have some troubles creating Winning situation in my game.
every time i open the app and click in any button it shows the winning massage.
can anyone help me??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int[][] table;
TextView tv;
Button btn, button, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8;
int counter = 0;
int X = 0, O= 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    table = new int[3][3];

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    whotoplay();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (counter == 0) {
                btn.setText("X");
                counter++;
                whotoplay();
                X = 0;
            } else {
                btn.setText("O");
                counter--;
                whotoplay();
                O = 1;
            }
            CheckResult();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, counter + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                button.setText("X");
                counter++;
                whotoplay();
                X = 0;

            } else {
                button.setText("O");
                counter--;
                whotoplay();
                O = 1;

            }
            CheckResult();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, counter + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and the same for the rest of the buttons,i add toast to make sure that the counter is working correctly.

```
public void whotoplay() {

    if (counter == 1) {
        tv.setText("O");
    }

    if (counter == 0) {
        tv.setText("X");
    }


}
```

and here is what did for the winning (its just for 1 situation )but it doesn't work.

```
public void CheckResult() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // horizantal
    if (table[0][0] == X && table[0][1] == X && table[0][2] == X) {

        dlgAlert.setMessage("X Player wins!");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("congratulations");
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        dlgAlert.create().show();

    }
```

as soon as i press for example btn, AlertDialog comes up.
please help me - i did almost everything i could.

Comment: then you are totally a winner that's not bad at all

Comment: by default your array is all `0` values so either change your logic or change array values, i'd prefer logic change

Comment: what do you suggest for changing logic??
how should i proceed??

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh which logic do you recommend for this app??

Comment: your code is quite incomplete , you can't make a tic toe game single `textview` displaying X and O in it , so i would recommend to google some tutorial first to understand the logic behind game then use android UI to create a game with same logic

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i understand ,i used that textview just for having enough information of the game,and honestly i searched alot and read different kinds of tutorials,the only thing i can't complete its this

Comment: see [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=create+tictactoe+android+from+scratch&rlz=1C1AOHY_enIN727IN727&oq=create+tictactoe+android+from+scratch&aqs=chrome..69i57.13214j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

Your culprit is hiding in plain sight:

```java
if (table[0][0] == X && table[0][1] == X && table[0][2] == X)
```

The problem is you defined `X = 0`, and when you create an int array, all values in it are initially zero. So your `if` up there always returns true the first time.

Changing your definition to `int X = 1, O = 2` should work, in which case zero represents the empty state.

Comment: because your code is incomplete , `table` values are never being changed hence same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your table is full of zeros at startup and you defined 'X' places to be zero (and 'O' as 1). So you need another convention:

- value for no pawn at all (place not already played), say 0
- value for 'X' say 1
- value for 'O' say 2

Comment: something else should be wrong. we don't have enough code to help now.

Answer (score 0):

i tried something else and it did work but in some circumstances i cant understand same problem happened again .

```
if(btn.getText().equals(button.getText())&&btn.getText()
.equals(button2.getText()))
{

        dlgAlert.setMessage("X Player wins!");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("congratulations");
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        dlgAlert.create().show();

    }
```

but when i try to use it for the next line or situation it doesnt work.